# Significance of the sign in the solution to the Friedmann equation

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, space-expansion, conventions

$$\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)^2 + \frac{k}{a^2} = \frac{8 \pi G}{3} \rho$$
The Friedmann equation contains a square of the first order derivative of the scale factor $a$ with respect to time. Correspondingly, there exist two solutions to the equation: one with a $+$ and one with a $-$ sign. What is the significance of the sign?

I don't think it means time reversal symmetry, because the time $t$ is usually raised to a fractional power in the solution for constant $w$-parameter.
$$a(t) = \pm\left(t/t_0\right)^m.$$

Comment: It has no significance. Only $a^2$ appears in the FRLW metric and therefore also in all other equations derived from it. We can just assume $a>0$.

Comment: @Prahar It has great significance! It is the difference between an expanding and a contracting solution.

Comment: @Dr.IkjyotSinghKohli - I thought that has to do with whether $|a|$ is increasing or decreasing not whether its positive or negative. How can the overall sign have significance when only $a^2$ appears in the metric?

Comment: So, as an example, let's look at expanding and contracting de Sitter universes. Very simply, an expanding de Sitter universe, we have that $\frac{3 \dot{a}}{a} = \sqrt{3 \Lambda}$, while for a contracting de Sitter universe, we have that $\frac{3 \dot{a}}{a} = -\sqrt{3 \Lambda}$. Solving the expanding case, we get that $a(t) = e^{\frac{\sqrt{\lambda } t}{\sqrt{3}}}$, solving the contracting case, we get that $a(t) = e^{-\frac{\sqrt{\lambda } t}{\sqrt{3}}}$. So,  $a^2$ for the expanding is different than $a^2$ for the contracting case. @Prahar

Comment: @Dr.IkjyotSinghKohli - I completely agree with your example. But nothing you have said is about the *OVERALL* sign of $a$ which is what the original poster is asking about. You are talking about sign $a=e^{\pm \# t}$ whereas OP is asking about the sign $a = \pm e^{\# t}$.

Comment: In other words, you are talking about the sign of ${\dot a}$ whereas OP is asking about the sign of $a$.

Comment: @Prahar So, in more general terms, $H = \dot{a} / a$. Expansion occurs when $H >0$, which means that the sign of $a$ plays a role, it must be the same sign as the derivative. For contraction, the sign of $a$ must be opposite to that of the derivative.

Comment: @Dr.IkjyotSinghKohli - Again, I am not disagreeing with what you are saying. All I am saying is that if I take $a \to -a$, it does not change $H$ at all anywhere (of course if $a \to -a$ then ${\dot a} \to - {\dot a}$).

Comment: @Dr.IkjyotSinghKohli No! You have an expanding universe if $a>0$ AND ${\dot a} > 0$. It has absolutely nothing to do with the sign of $a$ itself. It would also be an expanding universe if $a < 0$ and ${\dot a} < 0$. And of course all of this is because only $a^2$ appears in the metric so we can happily just assume $a>0$. Once this assumption is made an expanding universe has ${\dot a} > 0$ and a contracting one has ${\dot a} < 0$.

Comment: @Prahar but, this is what I just said, I don’t think we’re actually disagreeing about anything here.

Answer (score 1):

Positive gives the initial condition for an expanding universe, while negative gives the initial condition for a contracting universe.

For a barotropic fluid, we have $\rho \propto a^{-m}$, and so (assuming $k=0$ for simplicity) $$a^{m/2-1}\,da  \propto -dt.$$  Doing the integral gives $$a_f^{m/2} - a_i^{m/2} \propto -\Delta t < 0,$$ *i.e.* the change in scale factor with time is negative.